# How display following text using Text

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I want display following text in Text widget, the code below display text in their specific area. I want have something like this : word, word, word ...

Thx for helping me

```
import datetime

from tkinter import * 

import time

root = Tk()

ll = ['sa','fg']


for x in ll : 


    tt = Text(root,wrap=WORD)
    tt.insert(INSERT,x)

    tt.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of a loop, do `tt.insert(INSERT, ",".join(ll))` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inserting each word inside a for-loop, you can first create a string and insert the whole string. By the way, `tt.pack()` should be moved outside the loop in any case.

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

ll = ['sa','fg']

tt = Text(root,wrap=WORD)
tt.insert(INSERT, ', '.join(ll))
tt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```